# What is wrong with this mapping expression in my .vimrc?

Tags: key-bindings

I'm trying to make Vim play nice with wrapped lines and I'm running into some problems. The following line

```
xnoremap <expr> k ((v:count == 0) || (mode() !=# "V") ? 'gk' : 'k')
```

gives me the following error when launching Vim

```
Error detected while processing /cygdrive/c/Users/Chad/.vimrc:
line   76:
E749: empty buffer
```

If I remove either of the conditions the map will work fine but I'd like to combine them. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See `:h map_bar`. The `|` is used also as a command separator in vim, so you are executing a map command:

```
xnoremap <expr> k ((v:count == 0)
```

Then an empty command line, and after that a command:

```
(mode() !=# "V") ? 'gk' : 'k')
```

To use the `|` character in mappings, the two best options in my opinion are `<Bar>` or `\|`. Your mapping can be written as

```
xnoremap <expr> k ((v:count == 0) <Bar><Bar> (mode() !=# "V") ? 'gk' : 'k')
```

for example.

Comment: Ahh great! `:help map_bar` is what I needed. Thanks. That logic I posted is a little off for the behavior I want so I might have to end up using logical and instead but your solution does let me use `||` so I'll accept it as the answer.